# openresty proxy with oidc and set-cookie overwrites 3rd party session cookie

Tags: cookies, lua, openresty

I have an interesting issue with a setup.

I am using openresty proxy with lua-resty-oidc plugin to authenticate a otherwise not authenticated website.

In that website I have a webform that sets a cookie for its session.

Now when I test it in Postman the cookie stays present.

But when I am using the openresty proxy the cookie is overwritten, even if it has a different name than 'session' which is the default.

In my openresty proxy configuration the only thing I set manually is: `set $session_secret REDACTED`

I do not interact with any `set-cookie` in any way.

Maybe the lua-resty-oidc plugin overwrites all my `set-cookie`-s?